# I am costantly getting tuple errors and want to know what they are and how i can fix them

Tags: python-3.x, function, return, tuples

for example the code i am working on for school gives me a tuple error when i add the following multiple returns in this function

```
def GetHowLongToRun():
  print('Welcome to the Plant Growing Simulation')
  print()
  print('You can step through the simulation a year at a time')
  print('or run the simulation for 0 to 5 years')
  print('How many years do you want the simulation to run?')
  Years = int(input('Enter a number of years to run, or -1 for stepping mode:'))
  skipyear = input("Would you like to pause every year? Y/N")
  skipseason = input("Would you like to pause every season? Y/N")
  return Years, skipyear, skipseason
```

this gives me the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jonwe\Downloads\Paper1_ASLv1_2017_Python3_Pre (1).py", line 170, in <module>
    Simulation()
  File "C:\Users\jonwe\Downloads\Paper1_ASLv1_2017_Python3_Pre (1).py", line 154, in Simulation
    if YearsToRun >= 1:
TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'tuple' and 'int'
```

but if i were to just return the "Years" string it doesnt give me any errors and works perfectly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is how you process/unpack your return values.  I don't know what you currently have but it should be:

```
YearsToRun, skipy, skips = GetHowLongToRun ()
```

Assigning variables to your function should be the same order as your return values.

```
>>> YearsToRun, skipy, skips = GetHowLongToRun ()
Welcome to the Plant Growing Simulation

You can step through the simulation a year at a time
or run the simulation for 0 to 5 years
How many years do you want the simulation to run?
Enter a number of years to run, or -1 for stepping mode:2
Would you like to pause every year? Y/NN
Would you like to pause every season? Y/NN
>>> if YearsToRun >= 1:
...    print ('Do something.')
...    print ('Skip year: ', skipy)
...    print ('Skip season: ', skips)
... 
Do something.
Skip year:  N
Skip season:  N
```

Comment: i ended up just globalising the variables that i was trying to return but im sure this isnt a good fix that i should always use?

Comment: It's up to your preference.  If it works, it works.  I tend to minimize global variable because often time I ended up shadowing that variable inside my function.  Meaning, I used the same variable name inside my function without realizing it.